# UIView animation snaps into updated bounds before animation is done

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation, uiviewanimation

**Problem:**

I am trying to create my own custom search field with a desired growing animation (if you click on it), and a shrinking animation when the user taps out.

The animation behaves **weirdly since it moves out of the right screen bounds when shrinking**, even though the text field/search bar's right anchor is not modified.

Like so:

[image: animation of search field]

> Notice how the right side of the search bar briefly moves outside of the visible screen bounds during the animation.

**Expected behavior:**

The search bar should smoothly grow/shrink without moving the right edge position of the text field, i.e. have the right anchor stay pinned.

**What you see in above gif is built using the following code (by subclassing a `UITextField`):**

```swift
public class MySearchBar: UITextField {
    
    private var preAnimationWidth: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private var postAnimationWidth: NSLayoutConstraint?
        
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.backgroundColor = Theme.GRAY800
        self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        
        self.autocorrectionType = .no
        
        self.font = FontFamily.ProximaNova.regular.font(size: 16)
        self.textColor = .white
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [.foregroundColor : Theme.GRAY400, .font: FontFamily.ProximaNova.regular.font(size: 16)])
        
        // some further appearance configurations
    }
    
    
    public func setupGrowAnimation(initialWidth: NSLayoutConstraint, grownWidth: NSLayoutConstraint, height: CGFloat) {
        preAnimationWidth = initialWidth
        postAnimationWidth = grownWidth
        
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = height / 2
    }
    
    // growButton is called when the textfield becomes active, i.e. the user taps on it.
    public func growButton() {
        guard let preAnimationWidth = preAnimationWidth, let postAnimationWidth = postAnimationWidth else { return }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            preAnimationWidth.isActive = false
            postAnimationWidth.isActive = true
            
            self.layer.borderColor = Theme.GRAY600.cgColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = 2
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    // shrinkButton is called whenever the textfield resigns its first responder state, i.e. the user clicks out of it.
    public func shrinkButton() {
        guard let preAnimationWidth = preAnimationWidth, let postAnimationWidth = postAnimationWidth else { return }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            postAnimationWidth.isActive = false
            preAnimationWidth.isActive = true
            
            self.layer.borderWidth = 0
            self.layer.borderColor = .none
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
            
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is how the search bar is initialized in my `viewDidLoad`:**

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let containerView = UIView()
        
        let searchBar = MySearchBar()
        
        searchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBarChangedEntry(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        searchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBarEndedEditing(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
        
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let initialWidth = searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        let expandedWidth = searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, constant: -32)
        
        searchBar.setupGrowAnimation(initialWidth: initialWidth, grownWidth: expandedWidth, height: 44)

        containerView.addSubview(searchBar)
        stackView.insertArrangedSubview(containerView, at: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.stackView.widthAnchor),
            searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor),
            initialWidth,
            searchBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
                
        self.stackView.setCustomSpacing(12, after: containerView)
}
```

> The search bar is part of a container view which, in turn, is the first (top) arranged subview of a stack view covering the entire screen's `safeAreaLayout` rectangle

**What I already tried:**

I have to perform the animation using constraints, and I've tried to animate it without using the width anchor (e.g. by animating the leftAnchor's constant). Nothing worked so far.

Upon googling, I couldn't really find anything helpful that would help me find a solution to this problem, which is why I am trying my luck here.

I do have to admit that I am not proficient with animations of iOS at all - so please bear with me if this is a simple mistake to fix.

**So, why does the search bar behave that way? And how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tough to say, because the code you posted is missing a lot of information (for example, you don't show the creation of the `stackView`, nor where its being added to the view hierarchy).

However, you *might* fix your issue with this simple change...

In both your `growButton()` and `shrinkButton()` funcs, change this line in the animation block:

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to this:

```
self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

---

**Edit** - *a little explanation...*

To animate constraint changes, we want to call `.layoutIfNeeded()` on the **top-most view** that will be affected.

When calling:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.someView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

we're telling auto-layout to calculate the changes and then generate and run an animation... but only for `someView` and its subviews.

If our action is going to affect `someView.superview` - or, for example, the constraint change is going to move/size a *sibling* of `someView` or a sibling of `someView.superview`, we haven't told auto-layout to include those views in its layout calculations.

I expect there are specific implementations / layout hierarchies where one would want to specifically exclude some views from the layout / animation... but...

Personally, I do this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

because the constraint I want to animate might be on a subview deep in the view hierarchy - and could have 4 or 5 or 6 etc superviews - all of which could be affected by the change.

Comment: thanks a lot! works like a gem. Can you please explain why I have to animate the superview and not the view where I'm changing something? I'm not that good with animations and would love to understand

Comment: @linus_hologram - see the **Edit** to my answer for some explanation.